# Use a dynamic link as href in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have this in HTML:

http://abc.com/userid

This part is "http://abc.com/" static. "userid" is dynamic.

How to do this in XSLT?

Sorry if this is a repeat question, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: There really isn't enough information in the question to be able to answer it. You really need to say "what" you want to do with it, before we can answer "how". Ideally, can you show a small sample XML/HTML document, and your expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC: Sorry about this. Dimitre has got the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12623825/855410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an example how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
       <a href="http://abc.com/{userid}">Some link</a>
     </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<userid>SomeUserId</userid>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <a href="http://abc.com/SomeUserId">Some link</a>
</html>
```